Next.js App Throws ChunkLoadError on Startup for app/layout Chunk
Hello fellow developers,
I'm currently developing an application using Next.js and encountered an issue ChunkLoadError during the startup of my local development server. I have already tried deleting the .next folder but to no relief. The error message I receive is:
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk app/layout failed.
(timeout: http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/app/layout.js)

Environment:

Next.js version: Next.js (14.2.5)

Any advice or insights you can offer would be greatly appreciated!
import { Quicksand } from "next/font/google";
import "./styles/globals.css";
import UnsupportedScreen from "../components/UnsupportedScreen";
import Context from "./context";
import SplashScreen from "../components/SplashScreen";
import { ClerkProvider } from "@clerk/nextjs";
const inter = Quicksand({ subsets: ["latin"] });
import { NextUIProvider } from "@nextui-org/react";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Some Title",
  description: "Some Description",
  manifest: "/manifest.json",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider>
      <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; viewport-fit=cover"
          />
          <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
          <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
          <meta
            name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style"
            content="black-translucent"
          />
        </head>
        <body className={inter.className}>
          {/* <NextUIProvider> */}
          <UnsupportedScreen>
            <Context>{children}</Context>
          </UnsupportedScreen>
          {/* </NextUIProvider> */}
        </body>
      </html>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}


i think its sth to do with catch try hard refresh

CTRL + SHIFT + R

or remove your .next folder and rerun the app again
